# Random numbers in array without any duplicates

Tags: vb.net, loops

I'm trying to randomize an array from numbers 0 to 51 using loops but I just cannot seem to pull it off. My idea was that

1. Generate a Random Number
2. Check if this random number has been used by storing the previous in an array
3. If this random number has been used, generate new random number until it is not a duplicate
4. If it's not a duplicate, store it

My attempt:

```
    Dim list(51) As Integer
    Dim templist(51) As Integer

    For i As Integer = 0 To 51 Step 1
        list(i) = i
    Next i

    Do While counter <= 51
        p = rand.Next(0, 52)
        templist(counter) = p
        For n As Integer = 0 To 51 Step 1
            p = rand.Next(0, 52)
            If templist(n) = p Then
                Do While templist(n) = p
                    p = rand.Next(0, 52)
                Loop
                templist(n) = p
            Else
                templist(n) = p
            End If

        Next

        counter += 1
    Loop

    For n As Integer = 0 To 51 Step 1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(templist(n))
    Next
```

Comment: What is the problem? And your question is?

Comment: generating Random numbers in array without any duplicates is the question which is the title. the problem with my code is that it still gives me duplicates and i can't figure out a way to do it wihtout giving me duplicate numbers

Comment: Why are you storing numbers if you're trying to randomize an array? Are you trying to shuffle the contents of an array? Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle, don't store things.

Comment: Why does it have to be an array?  Did you find a time machine back to 1998?

Comment: No because this course does not cover how to use list

Comment: Smell some playing card game or similar stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a lot easier if you just have a list of all of the possible numbers (0 to 51 in your case), then remove the number from the list so it can't be picked again.  Try something like this:

```
Dim allNumbers As New List (Of Integer)
Dim randomNumbers As New List (Of Integer)
Dim rand as New Random

' Fill the list of all numbers
For i As Integer = 0 To 51 Step 1
    allNumbers.Add(i)
Next i

' Grab a random entry from the list of all numbers
For i As Integer = 0 To 51 Step 1
    Dim selectedIndex as Integer = rand.Next(0, (allNumbers.Count - 1) )
    Dim selectedNumber as Integer = allNumbers(selectedIndex)
    randomNumbers.Add(selectedNumber)
    allNumbers.Remove(selectedNumber)
    ' Might as well just add the number to ListBox1 here, too
    ListBox1.Items.Add(selectedNumber)
Next i
```

If your goal is to get the numbers into ListBox1, then you don't even need the "randomNumbers" list.

EDIT:

If you must have an array, try something like this:

```
Function RandomArray(min As Integer, max As Integer) As Integer()

    If min >= max Then
        Throw New Exception("Min. must be less than Max.)")
    End If

    Dim count As Integer = (max - min)
    Dim randomNumbers(count) As Integer
    Dim rand As New Random()

    ' Since an array of integers sets every number to zero, and zero is possibly within our min/max range (0-51 here),
    ' we have to initialize every number in the array to something that is outside our min/max range.
    If min <= 0 AndAlso max >= 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To count
            randomNumbers(i) = (min - 1)    ' Could also be max + 1
        Next i
    End If

    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    ' Loop until the array has count # of elements (so counter will be equal to count + 1, since it is incremented AFTER we place a number in the array)
    Do Until counter = count + 1
        Dim someNumber As Integer = rand.Next(min, max + 1)
        ' Only add the number if it is not already in the array
        If Not randomNumbers.Contains(someNumber) Then
            randomNumbers(counter) = someNumber
            counter += 1
        End If
    Loop

    Return randomNumbers
End Function
```

This is good enough for your assignment, but the computer scientist in my hates this algorithm.

Here's why this algorithm is much less desirable.  If zero is in your range of numbers, you will have to loop through the array at least 2N times (so 104+ times if you are going from 0 to 51).  This is a best case scenario; the time complexity of this algorithm actually gets worse as the range of numbers scales higher.  If you try running it from 0 to 100,000 for example, it will fill the first few thousand numbers very quickly, but as it goes on, it will take longer and longer to find a number that isn't already in the list.  By the time you get to the last few numbers, you could potentially have randomly generated a few trillion different numbers before you find those last few numbers.  If you assume an average complexity of 100000! (100,000 factorial), then the loop is going to execute almost ten to the half-a-millionth power times.

An array is more difficult to "shuffle" because it is a fixed size, so you can't really add and remove items like you can with a list or collection.  What you CAN do, though, is fill the array with your numbers in order, then go through a random number of iterations where you randomly swap the positions of two numbers.

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to do it without using List?

Comment: What do you want to use instead?

Comment: Well I was planning to use arrays only but I will go with this if I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While counter <= 51
            p = rand.Next(0, 52)

            While Array.IndexOf(list, p) = -1
                p = rand.Next(0, 52)
            End While

            counter += 1
        Loop
```

Comment: This is just an infinite loop.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Didn't notice that. :D

Answer (score 0):

Haven't written VB in about 5 years, but try this out:

```
Function GetRandomUniqueNumbersList(ByVal fromNumber As Integer, ByVal toNumber As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
    If (toNumber <= fromNumber) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("toNumber must be greater than fromNumber", toNumber)
    End If
    Dim random As New Random
    Dim randomNumbers As New HashSet(Of Integer)()
    Do
        randomNumbers.Add(random.Next(fromNumber, toNumber))
    Loop While (randomNumbers.Count < toNumber - fromNumber)
    Return randomNumbers.ToList()
End Function
```

Ok, that was painful. Please someone correct it if I made any mistakes. Should be very quick because it's using a HashSet.

Comment: Rnd() is very "VB6"-ish.  System.Random is the preferred .NET way of doing it.  Other than that, it looks good.  But if he can't use a List then I doubt that he can use a HashSet or Dictionary, either.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin thanks, I just replaced it with System.Random. I think it's probably better to populate an array with Min...Max, then shuffle the array a few times. The operation would take the same amount of time every time and be very stable. My solution could have unpredictable finish times. I would write it out, but coding in VB is very painful for me so I'll leave my answer as is.

Answer (score 0):

First response to forum on stackoverflow - be gentle.
I was looking for a way to do this but couldn't find a suitable example online.
I've had a go myself and eventually got this to work:

```
Sub addUnique(ByRef tempList, ByVal n, ByRef s)
    Dim rand = CInt(Rnd() * 15) + 1
    For j = 0 To n
        If tempList(j) = rand Then
            s = True
        End If
    Next
    If s = False Then
        tempList(n) = rand
    Else
        s = False
        addUnique(tempList, n, s)
    End If
End Sub
```

Then call the sub using:

```
Dim values(15) As Byte
Dim valueSeen As Boolean = False
For i = 0 To 15
    addUnique(values, i, valueSeen)
Next
```

This will randomly add the numbers 1 to 16 into an array. Each time a value is added, the previous values in the array are checked and if any of them are the same as the randomly generated value, s is set to true. If a value is not found (s=false), then the randomly generated value is added. The sub is recursively called again if s is still true at the end of the 'For' loop. Probably need 'Randomize()' in there somewhere.

Apologies if layout is a bit wobbly.