# Put different random value in each row of the database table

Tags: vb.net

I created the code below which giving me same random numbers result in every row.  I got 10 rows and 20 columns in my table. What I can add in my code so it give me different result in each row?

```
Dim conStr As String
    conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Try
        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(conStr)
            con.Open()
            Dim rndN As New Random
            Dim sqlStr As String = "UPDATE t_RandomData SET Column1 = @rndVal1, Column2 = @rndVal2, Column3 = @rndVal3, Column4 = @rndVal4, Column5 = @rndVal5, Column6 = @rndVal6, Column7 = @rndVal7, Column8 = @rndVal8, Column9 = @rndVal9, Column10 = @rndVal10, Column11 = @rndVal11, Column12 = @rndVal12, Column13 = @rndVal13, Column14 = @rndVal14, Column15 = @rndVal15, Column16 = @rndVal16, Column17 = @rndVal17, Column18 = @rndVal18, Column19 = @rndVal19, Column20 = @rndVal20"
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlStr, con)
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal1", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal2", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal3", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal4", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal5", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal6", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal7", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal8", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal9", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal10", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal11", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal12", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal13", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal14", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal15", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal16", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal17", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal18", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal19", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal20", rndN.Next(1, 99))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
            End Using
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Window", "alert('" & ex.Message & "');", True)
    End Try
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random numbers in array without any duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666175/random-numbers-in-array-without-any-duplicates)

Comment: Which rdbms are you using?

Comment: I Just want to know that what where clause I need in my sql string to make different random value appear in each row?

Answer (score 2):

You are using an `UPDATE` statement without a `WHERE`, that updates all rows.

```
Dim sqlStr As String = "UPDATE t_RandomData SET Column1 = @rndVal1, Column2 = @rndVal2, Column3 = @rndVal3, Column4 = @rndVal4, Column5 = @rndVal5, Column6 = @rndVal6, Column7 = @rndVal7, Column8 = @rndVal8, Column9 = @rndVal9, Column10 = @rndVal10, Column11 = @rndVal11, Column12 = @rndVal12, Column13 = @rndVal13, Column14 = @rndVal14, Column15 = @rndVal15, Column16 = @rndVal16, Column17 = @rndVal17, Column18 = @rndVal18, Column19 = @rndVal19, Column20 = @rndVal20 WHERE KeyColumn = @ID"
```

if you want to update all rows but with a different random value for every row you could use this sql based approach:

```
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 99
```

That generates a random number between 0 and 98, if you need 1-98:

```
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 98 + 1
```

If you need to persist this value for every row you could use:

```
declare @minValueIncl int, @maxValueExl int;
set @minValueIncl = 1; Set @maxValueExl = 99;
WITH RND AS
(
    SELECT Value = ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % (@maxValueExl - @minValueIncl) + @minValueIncl
)
SELECT RND.Value AS Col1, RND.Value AS Col2, idRMA, rnd.*
FROM RMA CROSS APPLY RND
```

**Update**: The last last approach presumed sql-server.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  where I can add SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 99 in my code

Comment: @kami: that is just an example how you get a random number with sql (in sql-server). What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I am using MS Access and want 1 to 99 number randomly appearing in each row

Comment: I might need sql command to update data row by row but don't know how!  Tried ROW_NUMBER function in WHERE clause but not working.

Comment: @kami: then use `RND` function: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/rnd.php But i'm not that familiar with acess to provide a working sample.

Comment: can you please provide me the sql version of the sample code to go in my code.