# How to create two different random integers and display them

Tags: vb.net

I've tried to make two different random integers but they always turn out to be the same number. I want them to be two different numbers between 33 and 126 and then display them, one of them on Key.Text and the other on Key2.Text

```
Dim RandomClass As New Random()
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
Dim RandomClass2 As Random()
Dim RandomNumber2 As Integer


RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next()
RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(33, 126)

RandomNumber2 = RandomClass2.Next()
RandomNumber2 = RandomClass2.Next(33, 126)
Key.Text = RandomNumber
Key2.Text = RandomNumber2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random numbers in array without any duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666175/random-numbers-in-array-without-any-duplicates)

Comment: Because you create both your random variables at the same time they'll get the same seed. That's why you get the same number. Instead create only one variable and use it to randomize all your numbers.

Comment: Though I don't see why you're calling first `Next()` and then `Next(33, 126)`. The first result is a Double between 0-1 and will be discarded since you change the value right after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) about the class `System.Random`:

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers. You can also work around it by modifying the seed value returned by the system clock and then explicitly providing this new seed value to the Random(Int32) constructor. For more information, see the Random(Int32) constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Charles!